# Android. Retrieve first name and last name from contact book by phone number

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am trying to get first name and last name in contact book by phone number.
Here is my code:

```
  Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
  Cursor cursor = cResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
  if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
            int firstNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
            int lastNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME);
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                long id = cursor.getLong(idColumnIndex);
                contact = new  MyContact();
                contact.setId(id);
                contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(firstNameIndex));
                contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(lastNameIndex));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

But *firstNameIndex* and *lastNameIndex* is always -1. What I am doing wrong ? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneLookup is a nice and quick way to get contact data by a phone number, but it returns a cursor limited to the [columns mentioned in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup#columns).

You can see there's `DISPLAY_NAME` you can access, but not `GIVEN_NAME`, `FAMILY_NAME`.

`GIVEN_NAME` & `FAMILY_NAME` are fields stored in the `Data` table, which means you need to query that table separately to get to those fields.

So, you can just add another query using the contact ID you got from `PhoneLookup` (note that for each looked up phone there might be multiple contacts returned).

Here's a sample method to get first/last names from contact ID:

```
private void addNames(MyContact contact, long contactId) {
    String[] projection = new String[] {StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME};
    
    // filter to just StructuredName rows from the data table for the given contact
    String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactID + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
    if (cursor.next()) {
        contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(0));
        contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```